# YouTube Data API - how to extract videos & channels info?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, extract, youtube-data-api, data-analysis

I am doing a very interesting project about **which variables make a video trend on YouTube** while others don't.

In order to do that, I'd like to extract as much relevant data as I can by using YouTube Data API. I don't have much experience with programming, especially using API's. What I intend to extract from some videos is:

- number of likes
- number of dislikes
- number of views
- number of comments

P.S.: given a fixed period of time (Nb. Jan. 2018 --> July 2018)

I have 2 main questions:

1) is it possible to do using this API?

2) how can I proceed in order to do it? I mean, what do I have to download, etc.?

Thanks in advance,

Matheus

Comment: You're negating yourself here. To work with APIs, you have to know about programming. No one's gonna write your software for you amigo. And, you're welcome :)

Comment: When making a call to [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#usage), use the "statistics" as your part parameter. It will return likes, dislikes, and views.

Comment: likes,dislikes and views are cumulative at time of query. The API does not provide this data for a fixed period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample on how to query videos based on a query text.
You can get whole lot of data from response

In C#

```
YouTubeService youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "yourkey",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = searchText; 
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 5; // 50
            searchListRequest.Type = "video";
            searchListRequest.VideoSyndicated = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoSyndicatedEnum.True__;
            searchListRequest.VideoEmbeddable = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoEmbeddableEnum.True__;

            SearchListResponse searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
            {
                if (searchResult.Id.Kind == "youtube#video")
                {
                    // Do something..
                }
            }
```